How to get a copy of libdevmapper 1.02.34 or later?
I am trying to update GRUB 2.06 to 2.12 on an Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS machine, following the instructions in the INSTALL text file included in the tarball (and at the bottom of the post). Reading through the prereqs (included below), I see I need libdevmapper 1.02.34. I don't seem to have this file, considering later when I run ./configure, ./configure's output ends with:
*******************************************************
GRUB2 will be compiled with following components:
Platform: i386-pc
With devmapper support: No (need libdevmapper header)
With memory debugging: No
With disk cache statistics: No
With boot time statistics: No
efiemu runtime: Yes
grub-mkfont: No (need freetype2 library)
grub-mount: No (need fuse or fuse3 libraries)
starfield theme: No (No build-time grub-mkfont)
With libzfs support: No (need zfs library)
Build-time grub-mkfont: No (need freetype2 library)
Without unifont (no build-time grub-mkfont)
Without liblzma (no support for XZ-compressed mips images) (need lzma library)
With stack smashing protector: No
*******************************************************

How do I obtain a copy of libdevmapper 1.02.34 or later?
Partial contents of INSTALL:
The Requirements
================

GRUB depends on some software packages installed into your system. If
you don't have any of them, please obtain and install them before
configuring the GRUB.

* GCC 5.1.0 or later
  Experimental support for clang 8.0.0 or later (results in much bigger binaries)
  for i386, x86_64, arm (including thumb), arm64, mips(el), powerpc, sparc64
* GNU Make
* GNU Bison 2.3 or later
* GNU gettext
* GNU binutils 2.9.1.0.23 or later
* Flex 2.5.35 or later
* pkg-config
* GNU patch
* Other standard GNU/Unix tools
* a libc with large file support (e.g. glibc 2.1 or later)

On GNU/Linux, you also need:

 * libdevmapper 1.02.34 or later (recommended)


...more content that I have cut out...


Building the GRUB
=================

The simplest way to compile this package is:

  1. `cd' to the directory containing the package's source code.

  2. Skip this and following step if you use release tarball and proceed to
     step 4. If you want translations type `./linguas.sh'.
  
  3. Type `./bootstrap'.

     The autogen.sh (called by bootstrap) uses python. By default autodetect
     it, but it can be overridden by setting the PYTHON variable.

  4. Type `./configure' to configure the package for your system.
     If you're using `csh' on an old version of System V, you might
     need to type `sh ./configure' instead to prevent `csh' from trying
     to execute `configure' itself.

     Running `configure' takes awhile.  While running, it prints some
     messages telling which features it is checking for.

  6. Type `make' to compile the package.

  7. Optionally, type `make check' to run any self-tests that come with
     the package. Note that many of the tests require root privileges in
     order to run.

  8. Type `make install' to install the programs and any data files and
     documentation.

  9. Type `make html' or `make pdf' to generate the html or pdf
     documentation.  Note, these are not built by default.

 10. You can remove the program binaries and object files from the
     source code directory by typing `make clean'.  To also remove the
     files that `configure' created (so you can compile the package for
     a different kind of computer), type `make distclean'.  There is
     also a `make maintainer-clean' target, but that is intended mainly
     for the package's developers.  If you use it, you may have to get
     all sorts of other programs in order to regenerate files that came
     with the distribution.


you should probably install it using your linux distro's packaging system. What is the system you're building this on, specifically? (ubuntu version)

@MarcusMüller Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. Sorry, should have initially included that!

so, apt search libdevmapper returns no development packages?

(also, honest question: That is going to run out of support eventually, have you considered updating to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS? Comes with a modern GRUB.)

if there's no recent enough libdevmapper, chances are you're best off compiling the libdevmapper (and ~-dev) package from Ubuntu 24.04, rebuild all software that depends on it, and then do the same for the Ubuntu Grub package from 24.04. That way, you'd get a Ubuntu that should still work within your environment, I guess. May one inquire why you need a slightly never Grub? Hardware bugs?

@MarcusMüller Sure, I would be fine with upgrading to 24.04 - upgrading to Grub 2.12 is proving to be a huge pain, if the Ubuntu devs do it for me that's all the better. I am looking to use Grub 2.12 because I would like to encrypt my /boot partition with LUKS2, but my current version of Grub (2.06) only supports LUKS1. I will look into updating Ubuntu!
If you would submit "upgrade to 24.04 and you'll get libdevmapper AND Grub 2.12", I would gladly accept that as the answer.

If you upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04, you get Grub2 2.12 and libdevmapper 1.02.185.
So, I'd take that route!

Thank you so much! You've put an end to a grueling few days of struggle.
